# Unable to draw table properly

Tags: tables, resize

I'm trying to make this table but its width is too large and so it gets out of the page. I tried a lot to fix it but unable to keep it inside the page margin. Is there any way to resize?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Numerical Comparison} \\
\hline
Region & FIESTA & MB & Old MOB & New MOB \\
\hline
$\bm{\mathcal{R}_{1}}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144}\\
$\bm{\mathcal{R}_{2}}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144}\\
$\bm{\mathcal{R}_{3}}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$)  & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} \\
$\bm{\mathcal{R}_{4}}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$)  & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} \\
$\bm{\mathcal{R}_{5}}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$)  & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} & \textbf{5.200296953044144} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need numbers with 15 decimal digits?

Comment: 4*3.5cm+2cm = 16cm + border of the paper and borders inside the table. That's too much space. Maybe you could use the [lscape package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape) to make the table in landscape orientation?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can reduce that to 10 digits. Will it work then? @Bernard

Comment: No. You defined fixed length with `p{__cm}`.  You could replace it with `r` (right aligned) and check the result. If you need too much space, reduce the digits.

Comment: Try, but you shouldn't decide in advance the width of the columns. Another problem is the value of \tabcolsep –  the default if 6 pt! This means  more than 12mm between columns.

Comment: Your `\begin{tabular}{...}` line is specifying fixed widths for the columns of `2cm`, then 4 lots of `3.5cm`.  You might try `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}` instead and see if that looks ok.

Comment: Yeah. Changing to 6 pt actually fixed it. Thanks a lot @Bernard

Comment: Is there any reason that you repeat ` (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$)` in each cell of the first column? Maybe the real table has different values for each row?

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Honestly, this table will go in a paper that's why I didn't want to put the exact values here before publishing. @Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a variant layout, where the specifications in the first column are grouped as table notes with `threeparttable`, and the numbers rounded to  10 decimal digits, using the `S` column type from `siunitx`, so that you obtain  correctly formatted and aligned numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[flushleft, online]
\sisetup{table-format=1.10, table-number-alignment=center, round-mode=places, round-precision=10}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ |>{$}l <{$}|*{4}{S|}}
%\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Numerical Comparison} \\
\hline
\text{Region} & {FIESTA} & {MB} & {Old MOB} & {New MOB} \\
\hline
\bm{\mathcal{R}_{1}}\tnote{a}& 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\
\bm{\mathcal{R}_{2}}\tnote{b}& 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\
\bm{\mathcal{R}_{3}}\tnote{c} & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 \\
\bm{\mathcal{R}_{4}}\tnote{d}& 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 \\
\bm{\mathcal{R}_{5}}\tnote{e} & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\small
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
  \item[a]s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$%
  \item[b]s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$ \\
  \item[c]s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$%
  \item[d]s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$ \\
  \item[e]s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to -- or need to -- show 15 decimal digits in all four data columns, the only sensible way forward is to display the material in landscape format. Whatever else you do, don't assault your readers visually by showing all numbers in **bold**.

In the following solution, I employ a `tabularx` environment. The first column is set to allow automatic line breaking, with hanging indentation from the second row onward. I've also gotten rid of all vertical lines to give the material a more open "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm,tabularx,amssymb,rotating,booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption*{Numerical Comparison}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    >{\raggedright\hangafter1\hangindent2em}X llll @{}}
\toprule
Region & FIESTA & MB & Old MOB & New MOB \\
\midrule
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}_{1}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\ 
\addlinespace
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}_{2}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\ 
\addlinespace
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}_{3}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\ 
\addlinespace
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}_{4}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\ 
\addlinespace
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}_{5}$ (s=0.5, t=0.5, m=1, $\epsilon=0.1$) & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144 & 5.200296953044144\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```